# Hold the output of pager (man,more, etc) in Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, freebsd, less

I want to apply the following from the freeBSD to the Linux systems.

When you browse through `man`,  pages on bsd for example, if you interupt it anytime, the pager will still show it's output, unlike linux systems. If I wasn't clear, please look at this f.e.

[image]

I find this very useful, so I am wondering can this be somehow achieved within Linux distributions?

Comment: Does the `-X` option help? Assuming you're actually using less and not more.

Comment: @muru yea, exactly that. But I don't wanna do something like `top | less -X`, f.e. would be 'overkill' . Is there any way to default this somehow?

Comment: you'd probably have to set TERM to something crap, maybe `TERM=dumb`. I wouldn't advise it, though

Comment: . . . or `export LESS='-X'` in your shell's initialization file maybe?

Comment: this is called the alternate display.  some people like it, some don't (i'm one of those who do - i don't want stuff from man or vi or less or whatever wiping out my on-screen shell history).   Some terminal emulators have preferences options to enable/disable it.  Or you can disable it by editing/over-riding the termcap entry for your $TERM (probably xterm or xterm-color or similar) - google for "disable terminal alternate display"..here's one that looks old but still useful: http://www.shallowsky.com/linux/noaltscreen.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the bash shell edit or create .bashrc and add the line "alias less='less -X'" omit the double quotes. Save the file, log off  and back on. Then whenever you enter less file the system will use less -X file. If you don't always want -X as an option you can use a different name as the alias like alias more=less -X to retain normal less functionality and give yourself an easy to remember alternative with the options you choose.